# Update column where column count < 2 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a MySQL database like this:

```
physicians database
Name   |   Specialty
----------------
Bob        Nurse
Susan      Nurse
Joan       Driver
```

I want to update the Database so that any Specialty that has a count of less than 2 is moved to `Other Specialties`

So the database should be updated like this:

```
physicians database
Name   |   Specialty
----------------
Bob        Nurse
Susan      Nurse
Joan       Other Specialties
```

The real database for this query is much larger.

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE physicians 
 (SELECT Specialty FROM physicians GROUP BY Specialty
   HAVING COUNT(Specialty) = 1) AS counter
SET Specialty = 'Other Specialties'
WHERE Specity = counter
```

But I'm getting a syntax error, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: The Update statement syntax doesn't allow the subselect construct you are using - ```UPDATE table (subselect) set column = value where condition```. You can remove the subselect but I'm afraid you don't really understand the consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE physicians 
SET Specialty = 'Other Specialties'
WHERE Specialty IN (SELECT Specialty 
                   FROM (SELECT Specialty 
                         FROM physicians
                         GROUP BY Specialty
                         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS t)
```

This `UPDATE` uses a subquery in order to get all `Specialty` values being unique. It then uses these values to perform the `UPDATE`.

**Note:** The subquery is wrapped in another subquery because its `SELECT` statement cannot be used directly by the `UPDATE` in order to update the same table.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GHL56749)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your query structure you may change it to

```
UPDATE physicians inner join   
(SELECT Specialty FROM physicians GROUP BY Specialty
HAVING COUNT(Specialty) = 1) AS counter on physicians.speciality = counter.specialty
SET Specialty = 'Other Specialties'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update physicians
set Specialty = 'Other Specialties'
where Specialty in (
        select Specialty
        from physicians
        group by Specialty
        having COUNT(Specialty) < 2
        )
```

Update :
   UPDATE physicians 
    SET Specialty = 'Other Specialties'
    WHERE Specialty IN (SELECT Specialty 
                   FROM (SELECT Specialty 
                         FROM physicians
                         GROUP BY Specialty
                         HAVING COUNT(Specialty) < 2) AS spacialityvalues) ;

Comment: This returns an error: [Err] 1093 - Table 'physicians' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data